# Regex: Catch images and images in anchors

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have no problem grabbing images from a page with the code below but how do I modify it to grab both images AND images wrapped in an anchor?

```
        $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse html code, instead use a dom parser!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1519058)...

Comment: Can you give some example input you'd like to match. Also, your regex will match from the first `<img` to the last `src=` on a single line. If all your html is on one line, this is a problem. Likewise, if there are any linebreaks it won't match at all.

Comment: Do you need to do that on server side? I mean, if you are grabbing this page from a site already published, you are a "Client", perhaps use jQuery instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to grab either the whole image tag or just the image name out of the string:

```
$string = '<img src="http://www.google.com/trans.gif">

<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.yahoo.com/images/placeholder.gif"></a>';

if (preg_match_all('/<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>/i', $string, $matches)) {
    print "<pre>"; print_r($matches); print "</pre>";
}
else {
    print "Could not find any matches";
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src="http://www.google.com/trans.gif">
            [1] => <img src="http://www.yahoo.com/images/placeholder.gif">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.google.com/trans.gif
            [1] => http://www.yahoo.com/images/placeholder.gif
        )

)
```

Explanation of the REGEX:

```
<img   .*?   src=   [\'"]   (.*?)   [\'"]   .*?   >
  ^     ^      ^      ^       ^       ^      ^    ^
  1     2      3      4       5       6      7    8
```

1. `<img` Look for a literal opening image tag.
2. `.*?` Match any character `.`, any number of times `*` until it hits the next part of the expression `?`.  In this case the next part of the expression is `src=`, so it will stop looking for stuff once it hits that.
3. `src=` Look for the exact text of `src=`.
4. `[\'"]` A character class meaning to match either a single or double quote.
5. `(.*?)` This is the same as number 2, except we put it in parenthesis so that we can capture whatever it finds.
6. `[\'"]` Same as number 4.
7. `.*?` Same as number 2.
8. `>` Look for a literal greater than sign (closing HTML bracket).

[Here is a working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR7uX8)